# Find values from one SQL Server database table not present in another table

Tags: sql-server, sailpoint

I have two tables with the following data (that I did not create nor can I control) that correlate on table1.workgroup = table2.id.

Table1

| identity_id | workgroup |
| --- | --- |
| 58173 | 158938173 |
| 98156 | 670451782 |
| 41930 | 159381738 |

Table2

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 158938173 | Sales |
| 670451782 | Engineering |
| 159381738 | Support |

I need to find where `table1.workgroup` does not have a correlating record in `table2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT workgroup
FROM TABLE_1 
  EXCEPT
SELECT id
FROM TABLE_2
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option:

```
SELECT Table1.workgroup
FROM      Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 
       ON Table1.workgroup = Table2.id
WHERE Table2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: probably want to add what Table1 and Table2 are joining on